# Statistical process control, z-scores in the equation of lower and upper control limit

Tags: confidence-interval, z-score

The equation is UCL or LCL is:
$$
\bar X \pm Z\times{\rm Standard\ deviation}
$$
I read an article about the z-score on [this webpage](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/021115/what-difference-between-standard-deviation-and-z-score.asp#ixzz4fG7bosL6) from investopedia. In one of the paragraphs it says:

> The Z-score, by contrast, is the number of standard deviations a given   data point lies from the mean. To calculate Z-score, simply subtract the mean from each data point and divide the result by the standard deviation".

Why do we need the Z (z-score) in this equation? Why don't you just remove the Z from this equation to make it more realistic? 
$$
\bar{x} \pm {\rm Standard\ deviation}
$$
What is the function of $Z$?

Comment: One standard deviation is not large enough to say that the system is out of control.

Comment: Why is it not large enough? If it's not large enough , why do people times the Z-scores to the Std dev to make it ' enough ' or acceptable as upper or lower control limit?  I understand the logic of standard deviation. But I dont understand the Z-scores. What is the logic behind it?  Thanks